# Clean Coding: Catching specific Mongoose error types

Tags: node.js, mongoose, error-handling, documentation

I like to write clean node.js code, which involves catching specific errors for Mongoose. From searching online, I found that error code 11000 means duplicate-key-error. However, I would much rather reference some sort of error enum. Something like `if(err.code=Mongoose.Errortypes.DuplicateKeyError)`. Does this exist?

Comment: I don't think there is one, I'm more surprised that you have to use this condition. Since `_id` is mostly auto generated. Are you manually creating `_id`?

Comment: Email field is unique. Nonetheless, this question may no longer be relevant since I realized lbyl is more commonly used with mongoose than eafp. With lbyl design, a generic catch-all at the end should be good enough.